# Creating a hibernate disjunction query programatically

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a chunk of java code which hard codes a hibernate disjunction query that looks like this

```
session = HibernateUtils.beginTransaction("outpatient");
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AugmentToken.class);
        session.beginTransaction();
        if (type == Constants.ICD9CPT) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", "d"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", "p"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", "c")));
        } else if (type == Constants.EM) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", "eros"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", "ehpi"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", "epe")));
        }
```

But this is not very elegant code.    What I would like to do is pass an array of codetypes to a method, and dynamically construct the dijunction criteria.   Every website I look at provides examples of disjunctive queries that look like the above, but this will not work for me because I don't want to hard code the construction of the restriction for the criteria since the number of code types can vary.

How do I do this?

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out.   You create the disjunction as a variable, then sequentially add to it.
Specifically:

```
 String [] codeTypes = new String[3];
 codeTyes[0]="d";
 codeTypes[1]="p";
 codetypes[2]="c";
 /* note the above would normally be passed into the method containing the code below */
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AugmentToken.class);
    session.beginTransaction();
 Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
 for (int x = 0; x < codeTypes.length; x++ ) {
  disjucntion.add(Restrictions.eq("codeType",codeTypes[x]);
 }
 criteria.add(disjunction);
```

I found the answer in Beginning Hibernate on page 214.   The book is accessible from books.google.com.