# Fetch database records using hibernate without using Primary Key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to fetch records from database without the primary key, for a table that i have created. Here is the model class for it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCTORS_INFORMATION")
 public class DoctorInformation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "DOCTOR_ID")
private int ID;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE1")
private String addressLine1;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CITY")
private Location location;
//along with setters and getters
```

It is very difficult to remember the Doctor_Id for every doctor, and logically First_Name or anything cannot be made a primary key. All the tutorials and lecture videos that i have gone through fetch records using **session.get** where session is an object of class Session. In the source code of Session class all the overloaded methods of `get` mandatory take id as a parameter...
Is their a workaround for the above problem?

Comment: where is your code for your DAO?

Comment: Why not just use HQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple options. All of the following examples search for a doctor whose lastName contains *Johnson*.

**Criteria**

```
String lastNameToSearchFor = "Johnson";
List doctors = session.createCriteria(DoctorInformation.class)
     .add( Restrictions.like("lastName", "%"+lastNameToSearchFor+"%") ) // the leading wild card can become a problem since it cannot be indexed by the DB!
     .addOrder( Order.asc("lastName") )
     .list();
```

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

**HQL**

```
String lastNameToSearchFor = "Johnson";
String hql = "FROM " + DoctorInformation.class.getName() + " di WHERE di.lastName LIKE :lastName ORDER BY di.lastName ASC";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("lastName", "%" + lastNameToSearchFor + "%"); // again, the leading wild card may be a problem
List doctors = query.list();
```

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

**Native SQL**

```
String lastNameToSearchFor = "Johnson";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM DOCTORS_INFORMATION WHERE lastName LIKE :lastName ORDER BY lastName ASC";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(DoctorInformation.class);
query.setString("lastName", "%" + lastNameToSearchFor + "%"); // again, the leading wild card may be a problem
List doctors = query.list();
```

If you want to add capability to search with, let's say *firstName*, then you might want to look into Hibernate's Disjunction: [Creating a hibernate disjunction query programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657283/creating-a-hibernate-disjunction-query-programatically)

Comment: i was not aware of HQL, Thank-you !